# grep change color highlight from first line to second line

Tags: grep

I've spent hours with a new 4K TV and nVidia GPU trying to get highest refresh rate possible. Just now I've setup a relatively simple `grep` setup to display connected monitors, resolution and refresh rate.

Results of `xrandr --current | grep -e " connected" -A1`:

[image: grep connected.png]

I want the current refresh rate (denoted by `*`) highlighted. When `connected` is highlighted on the first line it is visually distracting and redundant. If I `grep` a second time to highlight `*` on the second line the first line with output name disappears. That is not helpful.

How can I move initial `grep` color highlight from first line with a second `grep` and still keep the first line?

Answer (score 2):

## `grep` on EOL (End of Line character)

Running `grep` a second time to highlight a different word causes all other lines without the word to disappear. The secret is to `grep` on different word  **OR** the EOL character (`\$` or simply `$`). The full explanation is here:

- [How to highlight a word in the output of “cat”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106565/how-to-highlight-a-word-in-the-output-of-cat)

The new command becomes:

- `xrandr --current | grep -e " connected" -A1 | grep -E '\*|$'`:

And it returns this:

[image: grep refresh rate.png]

- `$` represents searching for EOL (End of Line) character which is on every line. This means every line from the first `grep` reappears on the second `grep`. The EOL character is not visible so you don't see `⏎` highlighted at the end of every line.
- Because the second `grep` is searching for `*` (which is a control character), it needs to be prepended with `\`. Normally you would simply use `word|$` to search and not `\word|$`. The asterisk (or splat) `*` character is an exception. See [Escaping Meta-Characters](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-grep-regular-expressions-to-search-for-text-patterns-in-linux#escaping-meta).

---

## Bonus Answer 1

### Enhance output by highlighting Hz values

Using the answer from: [Matching decimal number in grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446222/matching-decimal-number-in-grep). You can highlight the actual frequency rate in addition to the `*`.

This command:

```
xrandr --current | grep -e " connected" -A1 | grep -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\*|$'
```

Gives you this:

[image: grep all digits.png]

---

## Bonus Answer 2

### Enhance output with different highlight colors

The default red highlight color may not stand out well on your monitor. I know it is kind of washed out in my `gnome-terminal`. From this [colored grep](https://www.jefftk.com/p/colored-grep) blog you can create these aliases:

```
alias    grey-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;30' grep --color=always"
alias     red-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;31' grep --color=always"
alias   green-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;32' grep --color=always"
alias  yellow-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;33' grep --color=always"
alias    blue-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;34' grep --color=always"
alias magenta-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;35' grep --color=always"
alias    cyan-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;36' grep --color=always"
alias   white-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;37' grep --color=always"
```

For permanent availability (persistent across reboots) add them to your `~/.bashrc` file.

These commands:

```
xrandr --current | grep -e " connected" -A1 | green-grep -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\*|$'
xrandr --current | grep -e " connected" -A1 | yellow-grep -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\*|$'
xrandr --current | grep -e " connected" -A1 | cyan-grep -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\*|$'
```

Gives you this:

[image: grep colored.png]

- After trying all the colors I'm leading towards yellow as my favorite.